# Form Handling .php not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I insert a form in my blog [post](http://tectrick.org)

This code is inserted in the post

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

`name` and `email` text fields and a submit button.After that is create a welcome.php file.

**welcome.php** file code is as following.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
<?php get_sidebar('single'); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

but when i fille name and email in text filed and click on submit button. http://tectrick.org/welcome.php not found error and form is not processed

Comment: Please show your total form layout

Comment: Does `welcome.php` exists?

Comment: you should create template for adding this functionality

Comment: Make sure your path is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the code below:

```
<form action="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/welcome.php" method="post">
```

Comment: hello sir , thanks for reply . but this is not working .Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/mmtyw7mm/public_html/tectrick.org/wp-content/themes/tectrick/welcome.php on line 1

Comment: @Manumahajan Remove the `<?php get_header(); ?>` from your code and try again.

Comment: <form action="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

Comment: thank sir problem is solved after delete <?php get_header(); ?> . But how to show header on result file

Comment: You need to load WordPress in `welcome.php` file to accomplish it. Your code may look like this `include_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/wp-load.php';`. It basically depends  on where you are invoking WordPress from.